When are fin. dim. representations quotients of fin. dim. representations that are free over the base ring?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $G$ be a group (not necessarily finite). Let $\mathcal A$ be the category of (left) $R[G]$-modules that are finitely generated over $R$; one might call this the category of finite dimensional representations of $G$ over $R$. Consider the following statement $P(R,G)$:

For all $M\in\mathcal A$, there is an epimorphism $N\to M$ in $\mathcal A$ where $N$ is free as an $R$-module.

For what conditions on $R$ and $G$ is $P(R,G)$ true?
For instance, if $R$ is a field, then $P(R,G)$ is true for all $G$, since any $M\in \mathcal A$ is already free as an $R$-module. Similarly, if $G$ is finite, then $P(R,G)$ is true for all $R$, since any $M\in\mathcal A$ will be a quotient of a finitely generated free $R[G]$-module, which is in turn finitely generated and free as an $R$-module (if I'm not messing anything up in my head...).
Thus, the question is only interesting in the hard case: representations of infinite groups over a ring that is not a field.
Partial progress on a question I asked recently indicates that $P(R,G)$ is true if $R$ is Noetherian and $G$ is free; at the very least, it seems to be true (I haven't checked the details) when $G=\mathbb Z$ and $R$ is Noetherian local, and when $G$ is free and $R$ is a PID.

It should be true if $R$ is Noetherian and $G$ is finitely generated by other other question, what do you think? My gut feeling is that it doesn't hold in general.

Much more general question: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a Grothendieck abelian category. Let $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathcal{C}$ be a full generating additive subcategory consisting of projective objects (in your case, $\mathcal{C}$ is a module category, $\mathcal{D}$ consists of free modules). For which index categories $\mathcal{I}$ is the full subcategory $[\mathcal{I},\mathcal{C}] \subseteq [\mathcal{I},\mathcal{D}]$ also a generator? (In your case, $\mathcal{I}$ is a one-object groupoid, but I don't know if this restriction is useful, hence my comment.)
